# TypeLoadException on asp.net/xsp/mono on debian/opensuse

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono, xsp

When i reset apache and load my website i get the first error below. I have no idea what the problem is. If i reload the page again (without restarting apache) i get the 2nd error, probably because the first error occurred and BaseUser is the first class/func that Application_Start uses.

Why am i getting this load exception? Whats messed up is i tried using mono's VMWare img to debug it and i got the very same exception (until i restarted which now refuses to give me anything [but 404 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541949/asp-net-on-linux-mono-broken-weird-load-then-404-resource-error)). However when i use mono develop to run the project the site runs PERFECT. WTF.

Any ideas?

```
Server Error in '/' Application
A type load exception has occurred.

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.TypeLoadException: A type load exception has occurred.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod*,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.8.1 (tarball Mon Dec 27 10:20:03 UTC 2010); ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433
```

Second:

```
Server Error in '/' Application
Could not load type 'mynamespace.BaseUser' from assembly 'mynamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'mynamespace.BaseUser' from assembly 'mynamespace, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at mynamespace.Global.Application_Start (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod*,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.8.1 (tarball Mon Dec 27 10:20:03 UTC 2010); ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433
```

-edit- i'll mention that i tried MonoDevelops build of my site on both opensuse and my website and i get the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had lots of similar problems with Mono in Linux, but I managed to handle all of them.

I don't know if this works for you, but I would do `xbuild` prior to running `xsp`. It helped me lots of times, and I don't even know why it was required, since XSP is supposed, like ASP.NET usually does, to precompile the C# project prior to compiling the ASP.NET pages.

`TypeLoadException` occurs when the assembly's DLL cannot be loaded (in general also when the class is not present in the assembly, but that's not your case), so I guess that the ASP.NET's Bin directory is not filled with the application's code-behind DLL.

But... I also have a suspect: since mynamespace.Global.Application_Start is invoked, it means that your code behind **has been compiled already**, otherwise your error would be about the `Global` class.

Try with my advice and tell me what happens.

Comment: I dont exactly understand xbuild. What am i to do? do i just cd to the dir and type in xbuild? i did that and saw 0 errors, 20warnings. I deleted the main dll  and typed xbuild again and saw them created. I copied the dll and mdb file to my server, restarted and i get the same error

Comment: Why didn't you run xbuild directly on your server? Xbuild does the same as msbuild: it compiles your solution according to the .sln file or your project according to the .csproj file. It's like "make" without install, or "ant"

Comment: hmm, ok i'll try that. i didnt have the source files or solution on server. i'll let you know in a few mins

Comment: Also, does your assembly have notable dependencies that I should be aware of? For example, log4net, nhibernate...? Does the myNamespace assembly depend only on System assemblies?

Comment: so after modifying my prj file on server to change a link file into a file in the dir, i compiled and found that i forgot my mysql reference/dll file. After including that i now get the 404 errors that i got on mono's opensuse test VM image (link already in post but here it is again) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541949/asp-net-on-linux-mono-broken-weird-load-then-404-resource-error. No there isnt any dependencies. Just mysql and lucence which i used successfully on my other website which is currently running right now on the same server with no problems

Comment: I'll note that my first error was accidentally mkdir the wrong folder name (mv to rename solved that) then i updated apache to use /var/www/prjname/src (which holds ./bin and etc) instead of /var/www/prjname. I'm going to step out for food so i'll be away for a good hour

Comment: Yo dude, thanks for helping :). So dinner was quick and i decided to check up on something and it turned out the site config i edit wasnt enabled (and there was a copy in another config because of rewrite rules. i didnt understand apache at the time, how ordering worked etc). So after correcting that it worked. I'll mess around to figure out the problem but it appears that xbuild actually did solve it.

Comment: FUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU.......................... I was able to simulate the problem by renaming mysql.data.dll. This version of mono might give that error instead of telling me which dll could not be found as a previous version did. F$%^&. Whomever took that out needs to put that back. Maybe i'll downgrade mono to 2.6 (i am using 2.8.1). So, problem solved.

Comment: Maybe you can report it as a Mono bug. I'll go chat with them and tell about your question right away