# TypeLoadException on Asp.NET webforms on MonoDevelop on Debian

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, monodevelop, xsp

I have an Asp.NET Web Forms project that I imported from my previous Visual Studio directory on my windows disk. After I edit the code, the build is successful but when I try to run it with Xsp4 and MonoDevelop, it displays:

```
Application Exception
System.TypeLoadException
Could not resolve type with token 01000017 (from typeref, class/assembly System.Web.UI.ScriptResourceDefinition, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception.
Exception stack trace:
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in <44bdc1f1bb534c5383b404ef5647abcd>:0 
Version Information: 5.12.0.309 (tarball Tue Oct 23 17:04:56 UTC 2018); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.42000
Powered by Mono
```

The version is displayed in the above stacktrace and I am using MonoDevelop version 7.5 that I got from the debian repository.

I am using debian 9.

How do I fix this problem?

I have looked at this [TypeLoadException on asp.net/xsp/mono on debian/opensuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542077/typeloadexception-on-asp-net-xsp-mono-on-debian-opensuse) but it just says that I need the project's dll in the bin folder which I have.

Comment: BTW, with .NET Core announced in 2014, there is no more a reason to run ASP.NET 4.x on Mono. All should migrate to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: what version of Debian? what version of Mono? how did you install mono on it?